# "Run whether is logged on or not" fails in copying file within shared drive

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy a file using the intermediate local machine from a share drive to another share drive. This works fine when I used `Run only when user is logged on` buy fails when I use `Run whether user is logged on or not`.

I have admin rights on both shared drives.

```
copy \\XX.XX.101.1\share$\Settings\*.csv "\\XX.XX.101.3\share$\Settings\DailyAuto" 1>>"\\XX.XX.101.1\share$\Hanon\log output %date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt" 2>>&1
```

I expected all `.csv` files will be copied from `XX.XX.101.1` to `XX.XX.101.3`.

The log file is created successfully with the following error:

```
\\XX.XX.101.1\share$\Settings\SCHEDULE_20190722.csv
The user name or password is incorrect.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: I use the same domain User to run the task which means the scheduled task should also have the same read/write permissions in "Run whether user is logged on or not". Am I correct?

Comment: For the "%date%", I have copied your idea and it gives me the correct and identical result as expected.